# Is there a good summary statistic that indicates that a vector has a high average _and_ a high sum?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Suppose I have a large number of positive vectors of different lengths that are drawn from a heavy tailed distribution. I'd like to summarize them in a way that ranks the ones with a large sum and a large average over ones that have only a large sum or only a large average. For instance, say I have

A = [10, .1]
B = [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, ..., 0.6] (length 20)
C = [.1, .1, .1, ..., .1] (length 1000)

If I rank each by their average, I have A > B > C. If I rank each by its sum, I have C > B > A. But really, B is the most interesting to me, because it has the most big numbers.

I know that in this example, taking the median would give me what I want, but I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for in general—I can easily construct examples where the median wouldn't give me what I want.

Is this a standard problem? Are there standard statistics that would help me here?

Comment: $(mean)^2+(sum)^2?$

Comment: Note that in fact A has a larger sum (as well as a larger mean) than B so it might be difficult to justify anything which selected B.  Also note that the sum is the mean multiplied by the number of terms

Comment: @Henry well, imagine B had length 20

Answer (score 0):

Because sum and mean goes together by $mean = \dfrac{sum}{n}$, I suppose you can use either sum or mean together with $n$. Intuitively you'll want higher sum or mean with lower $n$.

Say that there are cases where two vectors have same sum or mean and same $n$, and you are interested in which vector has larger values. Median helps here.

If you say the vectors *can* somehow behave that median can't deal well, use [five number summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-number_summary) instead of only the median. That way you'll also know the 75th percentile and the max instead of only median.